# Redmine: Reset connection from apache when creating new project or add new task

Tags: apache, passenger, redmine

I've installed Redmine v2.5.1 but have some problems: When I try to create a new project, it resets the connection from Apache.

I've tried to use a different version of Passanger (4.0.44, 4.0.43) and Apache but I'm still receiving the message "Request header read timeout" when I try to create a new project.

Apache version - Apache/2.4.9

Thanks.

Passanger log:

```
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:46 +0300] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:49 +0300] "GET /stylesheets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.css?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:49 +0300] "GET /stylesheets/application.css?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:49 +0300] "GET /javascripts/jquery-1.8.3-ui-1.9.2-ujs-2.0.3.js?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:49 +0300] "GET /javascripts/application.js?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:51 +0300] "GET /projects HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:51 +0300] "GET /stylesheets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.css?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:51 +0300] "GET /stylesheets/application.css?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:51 +0300] "GET /javascripts/jquery-1.8.3-ui-1.9.2-ujs-2.0.3.js?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:51 +0300] "GET /javascripts/application.js?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:51 +0300] "GET /images/add.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:51 +0300] "GET /images/fav.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:51 +0300] "GET /images/feed.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /projects/new HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /stylesheets/jquery/jquery-ui-1.9.2.css?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /stylesheets/application.css?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /javascripts/jquery-1.8.3-ui-1.9.2-ujs-2.0.3.js?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /javascripts/application.js?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /javascripts/jstoolbar/jstoolbar-textile.min.js?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /javascripts/jstoolbar/lang/jstoolbar-en.js?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /stylesheets/jstoolbar.css?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /javascripts/project_identifier.js?1402487614 HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_strong.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_em.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_ins.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_del.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_code.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_h1.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_h2.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_h3.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_ul.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_ol.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_bq.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_bq_remove.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_pre.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_link.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/jstoolbar/bt_img.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:30:52 +0300] "GET /images/help.png HTTP/1.1" 304 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:15:31:17 +0300] "-" 408 -
62.80.171.162 - - [11/Jun/2014:17:42:22 +0300] "-" 408 -
```

apache log:

```
[Wed Jun 11 17:51:19.406025 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15518:tid 3036814192] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 62.80.171.162:17937] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: example.com
[Wed Jun 11 17:51:19.406050 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15518:tid 3036814192] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 62.80.171.162:17937] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: example.com
[Wed Jun 11 17:51:19.406821 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15620:tid 3020028784] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 62.80.171.162:18234] AH01626: authorization result of Require all granted: granted, referer: http://example.com/projects/new
[Wed Jun 11 17:51:19.406863 2014] [authz_core:debug] [pid 15620:tid 3020028784] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client 62.80.171.162:18234] AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: granted, referer: http://examle.com/projects/new
[Wed Jun 11 17:51:54.811971 2014] [reqtimeout:info] [pid 15518:tid 3028421488] [client 62.80.171.162:13357] AH01382: Request header read timeout
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a2dismod reqtimeout
```

try disabling this module

Comment: Doesn't seem a good idea, this module exists and is enable by default for a reason.

Comment: It's some sort of ddos protection (not really), you can safely disable on development server and maybe on production too.